# Adding Water to Stack of Glasses

Tags: algorithms, binomial-coefficients

I always wanted to know if there is any real-world application of Pascal's triangle than just coefficients of the binomial expansion.

I tried to solve this problem:

[image]

There is a stack of water glasses in a form of pascal triangle and a person wants to pour the water only at the topmost glass, but the capacity of each glass is 1 unit . Overflow takes place in such a way that after 1 unit, 1/2 of remaining unit gets into immediate below left glass and other half in immediate below right glass.

```
                        1
                      /   \                  
                     2     3
                   /   \ /  \
                  4     5    6
```

But, What if I am adding K units of water and wants to find a glass which has the least water in it:

Where, Glass will be found as:   `c`-th glass in `r`-th row

And I believe. If we could find this then it will not be difficult for us to find amount of water in any glass for which `{i<r and j<c}`

- Problem:

  **Input**
  Water added- K units and capacity of each glass as 1- unit

  **Output Expected** : `c` th glass in `r` th row having least water in it.

I tried to solve problem by keeping note of capacity of each row when it starts overflow:
and wants to know how to keep going with this method.

```
      1       max = 1, cap = 1
     1 1      max = 1, sum(coefficients)=2**1 = 2, cap = 2/1 
    1 2 1     max = 2, sum = 2**2, cap = 4/2 = 2 units 
   1 3 3 1    max = 3, sum = 2**3, cap = 8/3 units
  1 4 6 4 1   max = 6, sum = 2**4, cap = 16/6 units
```

#Not sure but this is how it seems to me for the rate @which water is being added.

```
                 1
              1/2   1/2
           1/4   2/4  1/4
        1/8   3/8    3/8   1/8
     1/16  4/16  6/16  4/16  1/16
```

`g(n,k) = g(n-1, k-1) + g(n-1, k)`

I don't know what is missing?

Comment: Your third row looks wrong... it should be $1/4, 1/2, 1/4$, right?  The recursion is right, and the remaining rows are correct given that mistake.

Comment: "I always wanted to know if there is any real-world application of Pascal's triangle than just coefficients of the binomial expansion." - yeah, and almost equally mysterious is whether there is any real world application of the number $1$. Seriously. You can't do *anything* with discrete objects without Pascal's triangle coming into play.